# How to Loop through query result and compare results with input field

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to loop through the results of a query and then compare each results to an input field, if the value is repeated it must return false if not the result is true, I know that I could use unique index in database to avoid repeated values and then catch the error, but in this case repeated values are possible but they can´t both be "active" there a column called "status" with two values A or I (active and inactive) so "clabe" value can be repeated only when one is active and the other inactive.
Controller:

```
function agregar()
{
    $this->load->helper('date');
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City'); 
    $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');        
    $Interno = $this->input->post('intern');
    $clabe = $this->input->post('clabe2') . $this->input->post('control2'); 
    $cve_banco = $this->input->post('cve_banco');
    $Banco = $this->input->post('Banco2');
    $Observaciones = $this->input->post('Observaciones');

    $data = array(
        'Interno' => $Interno,
        'clabe' => $clabe,
        'cve_banco' => $cve_banco, 
        'Banco' => $Banco,
        'Observaciones' => $Observaciones,
        'Fecha_alta' => $now, 
    );

    if($this->consultas_M->insert($data) == true){
        //redirect('Inicio/busqueda', 'refresh');
    } else{
        echo "Hubo un problema al insertar";
    }
}
```

Model:

```
function insert($data)
{
    $clabe = $this->input->post('clabe2') . $this->input->post('control2'); 
    $this->db->select('Clabe');
    $this->db->where('Status =', 'A');
    $query= $this->db ->get('cuentas');
    return $query->row();
    foreach ($query as $row) {
        $i = $row;
        if ($clabe = $i) {
          return false;
        } else {
            $this-> db -> insert('cuentas', $data);
            if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
                return true;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which columns combo can be unique?

Comment: remove `return $query->row();` for further processing in your model

Comment: The only unique column is 'Interno" which is the employee number or ID.

Comment: "but in this case repeated values are possible but they can´t both be "active" there a column called "status" with two values A or I (active and inactive) so "clabe" value can be repeated only when one is active and the other inactive. " this sounds like a case for a compound key

Comment: add unique key on 2 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved myself the issue, i´m posting in in case it helps anybody, it was easier than I thought.

```
function insert($data, $clabe)
  {
       $Status = 'A';
       $clabe = $this->input->post('clabe2') . $this->input->post('control2');
      $this->db->select('Clabe');
      $this->db->where('Status =', $Status);
      $this->db->where('Clabe =', $clabe);
    $q= $this->db ->get('cuentas');
  if($q -> num_rows() > 0){
    return false;
                      }else{
                        $this-> db -> insert('cuentas', $data);
                        return true;
                      }
```

And this is the controller:

```
if($this->consultas_M->insert($data, $clabe) == true){
            redirect('Inicio/busqueda', 'refresh');
          } else{
            echo "There was a problem";
            $this->load->view('errors/error');

          }
```

The only thing I needed and wasn´t doing was to select the "clabe" I wanted and then compare it with the input where user writes this "clabe". And then just a simple if-else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to have possible duplicated index ? If you want to have different rows with a common "index" for some reason you can create a column called index or something and add in your WHERE clause that index.
PS: in your model in the foreach loop's if condition use :

```
if ($clabe == $row){...
```

instead of

```
$i = $row
if ($clabe = $i){...
```

Comment: well "clabe" is the interbank number, the idea is that every employee has only one active "clabe" but if for any reason, user saves the "clabe" of other employee, it can be deleted (they don´t want to delete them) so what they do is that they change the status to "inactive" that´s why there could be two repeated values but they will never be both "active"

Comment: OK, so assuming the clabe is not the primary key of your table in your database just do a SELECT Clabe FROM [yourTable] WHERE Clabe = '$clabe' AND status = 'A'. If it return any row(s) then return false else insert

Answer (score -1):

```
function insert($data)
{
  $Status = 'A';
   $clabe = $this->input->post('clabe2') . $this->input->post('control2'); 
   $this->db->select('Clabe');
   $this->db->where('Status', $Status);
   $query= $this->db ->get('cuentas');
   $flag=true;

   foreach ($query as $row) {
        $i = $row;
        if ($clabe = $i){
          $flag=false;
        }
    }
  if($flag){
    $this-> db -> insert('cuentas', $data);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        $flag= true;
    } 
  }
  return $flag;
}
```

Your code will add it on first else block ad return. Instead it should check all the rows first to decide.

Comment: that might be a partial solution, but the question is about php not sql

Comment: @zedling quesion is with php code but OP needs solution to take out duplicates either by code or db as mentioned in problem. Efficient way will be db level constraint instead of code. OP is unaware of unique constraints using combination of columns

Comment: well I understand the point but they should be unique only when Status = 'A' when Status = 'I' the values can be repeated.

Comment: @AdrianJimenez checkout if current is expected solution

Comment: remove db call if you donot wannt te insert

Comment: wEll i want the insert when the $flag = true;

Comment: it will insert when flag is true

Comment: but it doesn´t i mean it should insert only in that case but it inserts even if the flag is false

Comment: didnt get u still can u elaborate?